# reading network path from batch file and writing it to another batch file using batch file scripting

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

**Background:**

I am a newbie to batch file IO, need help with following problem
I have a source file `applaunch.bat` whom contents are as follows

```
start /B /D "\\MainServTST01.XYZ.ORG\BuildQA\BuildTEST\1.33.4.2\Application\Client2" Client.lTracking.exe
```

I have another batch file `buildcopy.bat` which I am using to copy a build from a network path to another path on local disk, its content are like this

```
REM
robocopy \\MainServTST01.XYZ.ORG\BuildQA\BuildTEST\1.33.4.2\Application\Client2     D:\BuildInstance\QA_Copy /s /e /zb
pause
```

**Problem:**

In `buildcopy.bat` I am currently manually updating source path i.e.

```
\\MainServTST01.XYZ.ORG\BuildQA\BuildTEST\1.33.4.2\Application\Client2
```

I want to write batch script inside "buildcopy.bat" which reads source path i.e.

```
\\MainServTST01.XYZ.ORG\BuildQA\BuildTEST\1.33.4.2\Application\Client2
```

from `applaunch.bat` and updates it for source path of `robocpy` command in `buildcopy.bat`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `buildcopy.bat` as shown the entire batch file?  It could be done simply and replace `buildcopy.bat` completely, with the needed information.

Comment: buildcopy.bat is the file where i want to do scripting to read the network path from applaunch.bat in a variable and then use it a source for my robocopy command. BTW i got the solution by doing bit of googling, m posting it here soon.

Comment: as i am new user, site is not allowing me to answer my own question :)

Comment: Got solution from googling, this article helped a lot http://superuser.com/questions/514284/how-do-i-use-a-quote-as-a-for-f-delimiter-in-cmd-exe-on-windows-7
which is about how to use quotes as delims in FOR

Solution to my problem: inside buildcopy.bat i have to write like this
FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%i IN (applaunch.bat) DO (
set buildpath=%%i
)
robocopy %buildpath% D:\BuildInstance\QA_Copy /s /e /zb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from googling, this article helped a lot https://superuser.com/questions/514284/how-do-i-use-a-quote-as-a-for-f-delimiter-in-cmd-exe-on-windows-7
which is about how to use quotes as delims in FOR Solution to my problem: inside buildcopy.bat i have to write like this

```
FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%i IN (applaunch.bat) DO ( set buildpath=%%i ) 
robocopy %buildpath% D:\BuildInstance\QA_Copy /s /e /zb
```